# Jquery - How to add text from attribute name from input into label attr for and that input ID?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I don't know how to add name from my input into label attr for and same input as ID. They are in same div. Do you guys know how to do it ? Thank you.

Jquery:

```
$('input[type="text"]').each(function () {
  var name = $("input").attr("name");
})
```

HTML:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
  <label>Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="fname" value="" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just get the previous element of `this` input field and change its text with `this.name`:

```
$('input[type="text"]').each(function() {
    $(this).prop('id', this.name)    // set 'id' of input field
           .prev('label')            // get previous sibling element
           .attr('for', this.name);  // set 'for' attribute
});
```

Comment: Hi, thx for post. I don't want to change text i want put that text from attribute name to previous label attribute "for" and into same input as "id".

Comment: @user3342042 Then you should have mentioned about that in the question. Anyway it is also very easy: check the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes i forgot about it

Answer (score 0):

Use $(this)

```
$('input[type="text"]').each(function () {
    var name = $(this).attr('name');
    $(this).prev('label').text(name);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use ***.prop()***  instead of ***.attr()*** Since, ***attr()*** gives you
>   the value of element as it was defines in the html on page load. It is
>   always recommended to use ***prop()*** to get values of elements which is
>   modified via javascript/jquery , as it gives you the original value of
>   an element's current state dom element

```
$('input[type="text"]').each(function () {

     var name = $("input").prop("name");
     $(this).prev('label').text(name);
});
```